# How do I retrieve value from Azure Keyvault to cypress.config file

Tags: azure, cypress, azure-keyvault, cicd

I have created an Azure Keyvault with values such as username, password, clientid and secret id.

I need to access these values in the env in cypress.config.js

```
env: {
    baseUrl: BASEURL,
    username: USERNAME,
    password: PASSWORD,
    clientId: CLIENTID,
    clientSecret: CLIENTSECRET,
    scope: SCOPE,
  }
```

I tried accessing vault values in config by using $()

```
env: {
    baseUrl: $(BASEURL),
    username: $(USERNAME),
    password: $(PASSWORD),
    clientId: $(CLIENTID),
    clientSecret: $(CLIENTSECRET),
    scope: $(SCOPE),
  }
```

But it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly set the value from key vault inside your Source code file, But you can add a custom code referred from [**here**](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/key-vault/secrets/javascript-developer-guide-find-secret.md) to fetch the value from key vault in your code:-

```js
const { SecretClient } = require("@azure/keyvault-secrets");
const { DefaultAzureCredential } = require("@azure/identity");

const vaultName = "your-vault-name";
const url = `https://${vaultName}.vault.azure.net`;

const credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
const client = new SecretClient(url, credential);

const secretName = "your-secret-name";
const secret = await client.getSecret(secretName);

const env = {
  baseUrl: BASEURL,
  username: secret.value.username,
  password: secret.value.password,
  clientId: secret.value.clientId,
  clientSecret: secret.value.clientSecret,
  scope: SCOPE,
};
```

Or retrieving it in the code, You can create a variable group linked to your Key vault and use the secret as variable directly in your pipeline:-

[image]

Or you can use ***Azure CLI or Azure Powershell task*** to get the content of your file, Fetch the secrets and replace it like below:-

**My yaml code for Azure CLI:-**

```yaml
trigger:
- main  # Replace with your branch name

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

steps:

- task: AzureCLI@2
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'PowershellSid'
    scriptType: 'pscore'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: |
      # Get the secret from Azure Key Vault
      $keyVaultName = "silicon-keyvault9"
      $secretName = "dbpassword"

      $secretValue = az keyvault secret show --vault-name $keyVaultName --name $secretName --query "value" --output tsv

      
      $cypressConfigPath = "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/cypress.config.js"

      
      $content = Get-Content $cypressConfigPath

      
      $content = $content -replace 'dbpassword: password // Fallback value if not set in environment', "dbpassword: '$secretValue' // Fallback value if not set in environment"

     
      $content | Set-Content $cypressConfigPath
    failOnStandardError: true
```

**Output:-**

[image]

**My yaml code for Azure Powershell:-**

```yaml
trigger:
- main  # Replace with your branch name

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

steps:

- task: AzurePowerShell@5
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'PowershellSid'
    ScriptType: 'InlineScript'
    Inline: |
      # Get the secret from Azure Key Vault
            $keyVaultName = "silicon-keyvault9"
            $secretName = "dbpassword"
            
            
            $secretValue = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $keyVaultName -Name "$secretName"
            
            # Path to your cypress.config.js file
            $cypressConfigPath = "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/cypress.config.js"
            
            # Read the content of the file
            $content = Get-Content $cypressConfigPath
            
            # Replace the password with the secret value
            $content = $content -replace 'dbpassword: password // Fallback value if not set in environment', "dbpassword: '$secretValue' // Fallback value if not set in environment"
            
            
            $content | Set-Content $cypressConfigPath
    preferredAzurePowerShellVersion: '11.0.0'
```